# Storing InputStream as GAE Blob in DataStore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, apache-commons-fileupload

I have a model Entity `Image`.
Entity has a field of type: `Blob`.
To perform file-uploads, use `Apache Commons FileUpload Library`.
To get my file, i use following code:

```
    Image image = new Image();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
    try {
        FileItemIterator itr = upload.getItemIterator(req);
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            FileItemStream item = itr.next();

            if(!item.isFormField())
            {
                image.setImageType(item.getContentType());
                InputStream stream = item.openStream();
                image.setImageData(???); //How to Set Blob Data from Input Stream
            }
        }
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        resp.sendError(500);
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Streams.copy(input, output, doClose)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/util/Streams.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean%29) utility method that comes with Apache Commons FileUpload to copy the `InputStream` into a byte array and create a `Blob` from that:

```
InputStream stream = ...
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Streams.copy(stream, bytes, true /* close stream after copy */);
Blob blob = new Blob(bytes.toByteArray());
image.setImageData(blob);
```